# Need googlemap.enableGoogleBar=true for V2 to work for V3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

My code for asp and seems to work except for the googlemap.enableGoogleBar=true. I believe i am using V3 and this is why. Does anyone have any ideas how to make this work with my current code.

```
googlemap.zoomlevel=10
googlemap.width=700
googlemap.height=400
googlemap.useDelay=200 

'googlemap.errorMessage="This address was not found in Google Maps" 

'googlemap.noAddressSet="No Benches found" 

'googlemap.maptype="G_NORMAL_MAP" 

googlemap.enableGoogleBar=true 'show the Google Search Box bottom-left (true or false)

googlemap.GLargeMapControl=true 'show the Large Map Control  (true or false)

'googlemap.GMapTypeControl=true 

googlemap.GOverviewMapControl=False 

'Now you can add multiple address-objects to the GoogleMap-object
dim address,strState, StrStreet, strCiudad, Image, strPosting,strPopUp,strNote


if strAddress <> "" then
set address=new cls_address
'address.iconURL="http://martinsbs/maps/orange_pushpin.png"
```

Comment: Maybe it might be useful to let your post be read by an English native. I have a really hard time trying to figure out what you want to ask.

Answer (score 0):

v2 was deprecated and turned off several years ago (May 19, 2010). Try the [SearchBox](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#places_searchbox) in the Places API.